# Save attachments using sender name and then save to a folder and rename them

Tags: vba, outlook

I have this macro to save email attachments using sender name. However, it isn't work. Can you help me?

```
Public Sub saveattachment(email As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim anexo As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim caminho As String
    Dim mes As String
    Dim ano As String
    Dim dataRena As String
    Dim dataRena2 As String
    Dim dataCall As String

    'let´s find which month, mmmm, to save the workbook
    Month = "March"
    Year = CStr(Year(Date))

    'save email using sendername
    Select Case email.SenderName
    Case "Adam Smith"
        caminho = "C:\Users\Barack.Obama\Desktop"
        For Each anexo In email.Attachments
            If Right(anexo.DisplayName, Len(anexo.DisplayName) - _
                InStrRev(anexo.DisplayName, ".")) = "xls" Then
                anexo.SaveAsFile (caminho & "\" & "Obama.xls")
            ElseIf Right(anexo.DisplayName, Len(anexo.DisplayName) - _
            InStrRev(anexo.DisplayName, ".")) = "xlsx" Then
                anexo.SaveAsFile (caminho & "\" & "Obama.xlsx")
            End If
            Set anexo = Nothing
        Next
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. How _exactly_ is this code now working? What happens and is there anything you already have done to try and fix it? Also, how do you trigger this macro?

Comment: the problem probably is in "Select Case email.SenderName"

Comment: Please add context to your question. If there are errors, which line? Also, how is this routing called? Are you using rules? Is this called by another macro?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the following piece of code:

```
    For Each anexo In email.Attachments
        If Right(anexo.DisplayName, Len(anexo.DisplayName) - _
            InStrRev(anexo.DisplayName, ".")) = "xls" Then
            anexo.SaveAsFile (caminho & "\" & "Obama.xls")
        ElseIf Right(anexo.DisplayName, Len(anexo.DisplayName) - _
        InStrRev(anexo.DisplayName, ".")) = "xlsx" Then
            anexo.SaveAsFile (caminho & "\" & "Obama.xlsx")
        End If
        Set anexo = Nothing
    Next
```

The fact is that if you have multiple attachments in the collection they may overwrite each other on the disk because you save files with the same name. Try to use individual file names instead:

```
     For Each anexo In email.Attachments
        If Right(anexo.DisplayName, Len(anexo.DisplayName) - _
            InStrRev(anexo.DisplayName, ".")) = "xls" Then
            anexo.SaveAsFile (caminho & "\" & anexo.Index & "Obama.xls")
        ElseIf Right(anexo.DisplayName, Len(anexo.DisplayName) - _
        InStrRev(anexo.DisplayName, ".")) = "xlsx" Then
            anexo.SaveAsFile (caminho & "\" & anexo.Index & "Obama.xlsx")
        End If
        Set anexo = Nothing
    Next
```

So, each attachment will have the unique name.

Also I'd suggest creating a folder for each email.